# Getting worse search performance with a replica shard

Tags: elasticsearch

To increase search performance, I tried to add a replica to my cluster.
Initially, I measured a response time of around 700ms for a specific request with a single node with a primary shard.
After adding a node and a replica shard to the cluster, it takes averagely 2000ms to get the result of the request (so it almost tripled).

I'm using these configs for the replica :

```
cluster.name: findmyfpstore
node.name: fmfs_r1
node.master: false
network.host: ...
http.port: ...
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ['...']
index.number_of_shards: 1
index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Feel free to tell me if you need more informations, I'm a beginner at ElasticSearch.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I tried with 2 shards, 1 replica, it doesn't change much

Comment: How many Elasticsearch nodes are you running? What sort of specs are these machines? Are you using SSD?

Comment: Hi, there are two nodes, each of the nodes are running on one different server (32go RAM, 8 cores). They don't use SSD.

Comment: Since you're using a single shard, I'm not sure you would see any significant performance boost by adding a replica, however, you also shouldn't get any performance hit because of it. What happens if you use 2 shards and 1 replica?

Comment: Are multiple shards useful if the data volume is really low ? I only have < 1k documents and it probably won't be higher. I'm trying it and I'll give you the results as soon as possible.

Comment: What is your document size? Can you share your query? Maybe we can improve that..

Comment: Document size is 829, I use two different queries, the first one tries to recover the closest store from a specified location, it looks like that :   
geoDistanceSorter := elastic.NewGeoDistanceSort("location").
   Point(aCoord.Lat, aCoord.Lon).
   Unit("km").
   GeoDistance("plane").
   Asc()

  // query execution
  matchAllQuery := elastic.NewMatchAllQuery()
  searchResult, err := client.Search().
   Index(indexName).
   Type(storeType).
   Query(matchAllQuery).
   Size(1).
   SortBy(geoDistanceSorter).
   Do() <=> uses a match all query with a geo distance sort

Comment: Try using the profile api on both single shard and 1 shard 1 replica. And see the difference. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of elements that can affect the performance of your cluster and query speeds.

I suggest you follow Elasticsearch's [Production Deployment](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/deploy.html) document, this will give you a lot of insight on how to properly configure your cluster.